# 1-D Peak Finding Algorithm for Multiple Peaks

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Currently I'm referring to the explanation given for finding a peak in 1-D array at below video tutorial by MIT OpenCourseWare.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HtSuA80QTyo

The recurrence relation : `T(n)=T(n/2) + O(1)` emphasizes only on one half of array plus it will result into one peak as an output. What could have been the recurrence relation having said that multiple peak do exist.

Please someone put some light on this query.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: @user2190060 good video but almost get asleep by watching it only through the half of it ... If you want to expand the algorithm to detect all the peaks not just one then you have to use different algorithm so you can not use recurrence  from single peak algorithm. btw for detecting all the peaks I do not think there is better solution then O(n) unless some more info about input data is known (like min peaks distance ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the video is: Find One peak in a 1-D array `A[0...N-1]` where `A[i]` is a peak when `A[i] >= A[i-1] and A[i] >= A[i+1]` or `i = 0 and A[i] >= A[i+1]` or `i = N-1 and A[i] >= A[i-1]`. An array may have many peaks, note that you just need to give any ONE. This problem can be solved by a divide and conquer algorithm. I implemented it in `C`.

```
// it return the index of the peak.
//it can contain many peak, you can return Any One.

int find_a_peak(int a[], int low, int hi) {
   if (low == hi) return low;
   if (low == hi - 1) return a[low] > a[hi] ? low : hi;
   int mid = (low + hi) / 2;
   if (a[mid] >= a[mid+1]) {
     //At least one peak can be found in the subarray A[low,low+1,...,mid]
     return find_a_peak(a, low, mid);
   } else {
     //At least one peak can be found in the subarray A[mid+1,...,hi]
     return find_a_peak(a, mid+1, hi); 
   } 
}
```

In fact, this algorithm is the same as binary search. You can cut the array by a half size at each step. That is `T(N) = T(N/2) + O(1)`, such that `T(N) = O(lnN`).